# How can I render a bokeh ChordPlot class?

Tags: python, bokeh, subclassing, holoviews

I'm currently trying to figure out how to render a holoviews element that I subclassed and passed to a Bokeh ChordPlot class.

Here's what I have so far:

In a jupyter notebook if you add bokeh extension to holoviews, it will render a holoviews Chord plot.

```
hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.output(size=200)
```

[chordclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J687f.png)

My boss wants a custom Chord Plot (can provide details if wanted), so I subclassed the holoviews Chord class, just using a stub for now to see if the subclass would render

```
class myChord(hv.Chord):
    pass

subclass = myChord(center_links)

chordclass = hv.Chord(center_links)
```

subclass returns a dataset

```
:myChord   [root,node]   (count)
```

and chordclass returns the plot above in Jupyter

Subclass is of type

```
__main__.myChord
```

and chordclass is of type

```
holoviews.element.graphs.Chord
```

so, the renderer store doesn't have my subclass name in it

```
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')

renderer.get_plot(subclass)

SkipRendering: No plotting class for myChord found
```

however there is a ChordPlot class in Bokeh that creates plot data

```
from holoviews.plotting.bokeh.graphs import ChordPlot

subclassPlot = ChordPlot(subclass)

type(subclassPlot) 

holoviews.plotting.bokeh.graphs.ChordPlot
```

I started looking into how the hv.renderer works, and am not sure if I'm on the right track

**I would like to know how to render subclassPlot, or get the subclass to be of type holoviews.element.graphs.Chord -- if possible**

A few questions:

1. Can I render a ChordPlot with Bokeh (or is it all an internal black box that hv.renderer uses?)
2. Should I be looking at how hv.renderer('bokeh') does it?
3. If there is a simple way of rendering ChordPlot wiht Bokeh API, can you point me to the classes/methods/place in the docs I will  need?

Any pointers this community could give would be highly appreciated.

Thanks